# Wordpress - Remove submenu from admin panel

Tags: wordpress, tags, portfolio

I'm trying to remove a "Tags" submenu from my Portfolio menu, this is what I'm using:

```
  add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

        function my_remove_menu_pages() {
        if(!current_user_can('create_users')) {
            remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'tags.php' );
            remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&post_type=portfolio' );
     }
    }
```

But it simply won't go. Here's the output of a var_dump($submenu); function:

Stackoverflow requires more text to the post ¬¬ so text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

```
array(12) {
  ["index.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Início"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "read"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "index.php"
    }
  }
  ["edit.php"]=>
  array(4) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Todos os Posts"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "edit.php"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Adicionar Novo"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(12) "post-new.php"
    }
    [15]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Categorias"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "manage_categories"
      [2]=>
      string(31) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category"
    }
    [16]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Tags"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "manage_categories"
      [2]=>
      string(31) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag"
    }
  }
  ["upload.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Biblioteca"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "upload_files"
      [2]=>
      string(10) "upload.php"
    }
  }
  ["link-manager.php"]=>
  array(3) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Todos os Links"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "manage_links"
      [2]=>
      string(16) "link-manager.php"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Adicionar novo"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "manage_links"
      [2]=>
      string(12) "link-add.php"
    }
    [15]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(19) "Categorias de Links"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "manage_categories"
      [2]=>
      string(36) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=link_category"
    }
  }
  ["edit.php?post_type=page"]=>
  array(2) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "Todas as Páginas"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_pages"
      [2]=>
      string(23) "edit.php?post_type=page"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Adicionar Nova"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_pages"
      [2]=>
      string(27) "post-new.php?post_type=page"
    }
  }
  ["edit-comments.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "Todos os Comentários"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(17) "edit-comments.php"
    }
  }
  ["edit.php?post_type=portfolio"]=>
  array(4) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "Portfolio"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(28) "edit.php?post_type=portfolio"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Adicionar Novo"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(32) "post-new.php?post_type=portfolio"
    }
    [15]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Tags"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "manage_categories"
      [2]=>
      string(55) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag&amp;post_type=portfolio"
    }
    [16]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "Categorias de Portfolio"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "manage_categories"
      [2]=>
      string(65) "edit-tags.php?taxonomy=portfolio_category&amp;post_type=portfolio"
    }
  }
  ["edit.php?post_type=slideshow"]=>
  array(2) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "Banners"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(28) "edit.php?post_type=slideshow"
    }
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "Adicionar Novo"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(32) "post-new.php?post_type=slideshow"
    }
  }
  ["themes.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [10]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "Menus"
      [1]=>
      string(18) "edit_theme_options"
      [2]=>
      string(13) "nav-menus.php"
    }
  }
  ["profile.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "Seu perfil"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "read"
      [2]=>
      string(11) "profile.php"
    }
  }
  ["tools.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(12) "Disponíveis"
      [1]=>
      string(10) "edit_posts"
      [2]=>
      string(9) "tools.php"
    }
  }
  ["options-general.php"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      string(16) "Support settings"
      [1]=>
      int(1)
      [2]=>
      string(16) "support_settings"
      [3]=>
      string(16) "Support settings"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use that `var_dump` within a `<pre>` element (or cut-paste its output from `view:source`) so you get some whitespace and its not a big blob of text like that...

Comment: also fyi, there's a [WordPress specific StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), though it seems as though its ok to post WP questions here as well.

Comment: thanks for the <pre> tip Zach, I've edited it

Answer (score 1):

The example put forth on the [Codex page for `remove_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) sets the optional 3rd parameter on [`add_action`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to `999` for the "priority".

I'm not sure if adding this to your code will make it work, but its worth a try.

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
  $page = remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );
}

?>
```